# write Session values to a text file in a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, session, jstl

I have to write session values to a a text file in a JSP page. I was able to retrieve the values of the session using following JSTL code.

```
<c:forEach items="${chapters}" var="name">  
  <c:out value="Iteration..."/>  
  <c:out value="${name}"/>  
</c:forEach>
```

After retrieving values , i have to write these values to a text file , and the following sample [code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/SaveFormInputtoFileusingJSP.htm) works well. But i cannot use JSTL tags inside JSP tags (<% ... %>).

1.Is it possible to use JSTL value inside JSP tags?

2.How to retrieve the session value inside JSP tags ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to write text file using `JSP`. It's better to use `backend technology` so you need to use `servlet for that which is made for that`, this type of operation must be done by `Server Side`.

If still you want to do so you can do it using `scriplet` tag :

```
<c:set var="name" value="${name}"/>

<%@ page import="java.io.*"  %>
<%
    String str = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionName");
    String name = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("name");
    String nameOfTextFile = "/resources/data.txt";
    try {   
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(nameOfTextFile));
        pw.println(str);
        pw.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
       out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
%>
```

Comment: Writing to text file is working fine , but my problem is getting session details inside JSP tags . Since i cannot use JSTL code inside JSP tags .. I am looking for a way to access session variable object details inside JSP tag. Hope i made it clear , thank you

Comment: @user3421325 : check my updated answer, i think you need to cast session value to string so I have used `(String)`. Post me what you get.

Comment: It was useful . "${chapters.name}" How to get this value within JSP tags?

Comment: how to check the number of entries in a session array ?

Comment: what is `${chapters.name}`, is it from servlet ? from where it comes ?

Comment: "chapters" is the session array and "name" is a value form session...

In JSTL i was able to get the value from "${chapters.name}"

Answer (score 0):

Use a servlet for that. JSP is just a view technology.